Are there other Pig families that aren't related to Peppa?
In Peppa Pig we're aware the families are animals, but every family is a single different animal. Even Grandpa Pig and Grandma Pig are the same animal.
When (if!) George and Peppa grow up, who will they have children with?

As far as other families are concerned, this one is fairly simple. There appear to be no shortage of cats, dogs, rabbits, lions, elephants, badgers, goats, sheep, cows, bulls, rhinos, etc. in the world.
We see multiple examples of animals of all sorts, both mundane and exotic when Peppa flies to America, flies to Paris, flies to Italy, goes to London, etc.



That all being said, there don't appear to be any other pigs depicted. Maybe they're pretty rare, but we can probably assume that they do exist and are simply not shown at the moment we're passing. For example, when Peppa and her family visit France and Daddy Pig drives on the wrong side of the road, a driver yells a warning about there being a pig in the road ("aaa-eee, une cochone de la rue") so clearly their species is instantly recognisable.
